# Windows 8 - Fresh Install Freezing after "diskpart clean" and rebuilding partitions

Tags: windows-8, diskpart

After accidentally allowing Ubuntu to install Grub on Windows' MBR partition, I am trying to start the system over from scratch to get things done properly.

In order to rebuild everything, I did the following from the windows command prompt using the recovery cd:

```
c:\diskpart
DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> clean
DISKPART> create partition efi size=102
DISKPART> create partition msr size=31
DISKPART> create partition primary size=150000
DISKPART> exit
```

After rebooting and trying an install, I get to the actual install process and select to install on the primary partition with no errors.

After a minute or so, it hangs at "Copying Files (0%)". The hang is such that no mouse movements and so forth can take place. I've let it sit for about 30 minutes to no avail.

If I try it again after rebooting, Windows will not let me install on the primary partition with the following error message:

"Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. This hard disck space is formatted with an unsupported version of the NTFS file system. Please back up any data you have on this partition. Then, restart the computer using the Windows installation disc (...and so forth)."

I follow these instructions (advanced options -> format) and am able to proceed again with the install, but once again the freeze takes place.

I have performed this entire process multiple times now. What am I missing? Clearly it's starting to do SOMETHING because the partition must be reformatted after the frozen install.

Note that I have previously (today) installed Windows 8 from this disk, however, during that time the MBR was still consumed by Grub (I was hopeful that doing the windows install would fix the MBR). Therefore I am positive the disk itself is functional.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Nevermind. If I delete all partitions from the custom install menu, and then use "new", and allow Windows to create its own partitions, the install performs as expected.